# How can I generate bitcoin cash addresses programmatically?

Tags: address, address-generation

If I'm a mobile developer who wants to integrate bitcoin cash in an app, how can I generate Bitcoin Cash addresses programmatically, without relying on a 3rd party service, like Coinbase?

Comment: You can use the exact same method used to generate Bitcoin addresses.  There is one parameter to change, as far as I know, and that is the part of the "[path](https://github.com/axic/bip32-path)" that identifies the type of cryptocurrency the address is for.

Comment: mobile developer? which language? there are many libraries to generate bitcoin addresses.

Comment: @Adam: iOS, Swift would be preferable.

Comment: @DaveScotese: The exact method being.....?

Comment: @p3scobar HD Protocol, HD Wallet, BIP32, which is described at https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/hd-protocol with links to some helpful resources.

Comment: You might also want to see https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md to verify that your addresses should be generated at the m/44/145/ derivation path

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library to generate bitcoin address using Swfit on IOS

https://github.com/onmyway133/AddressGenerator

Please note that the legacy bitcoin cash and bitcoin address is the same the only difference is the network.

if you're looking for cashAddr (qq address) format, take a look on these open source libraries:

https://github.com/bitcoincashjs/cashaddrjs (javascript)
https://cashaddr.bitcoincash.org/
https://github.com/schancel/cashaddr-converter

Original cashAddr algorithm (C++)

https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/master/src/cashaddr.cpp

it's pretty easy to read and understand, you can translate it to any language.

Comment: I believe OP may be asking for a way to generate cashaddr addresses.

Comment: Thanks for mention that, I've edited my question by adding more details.